# version 0.9.7a of openssl reports "certificate signature failed", but version 0.9.8e is happy

Tags: centos, ssl-certificate, openssl, certificate

I am trying to construct an openssl certificate chain that will work with a standard CentOS 4 install as client.  (I know it's very old, but it's what our client is using so we need to support it).

The first problem is that the CentOS 4 openssl CA bundle doesn't contain all the modern certificates, in particular the GoDaddy root certificate

```
/C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
```

So I've dug around and found a Valicert certificate for the above certificate and put it in the chain.  Running `openssl s_client` on CentOS 5 (which is openssl 0.9.8e) this chain verifies, but on CentOS 4 (which is openssl 0.9.7a) it doesn't verify.

CentOS 5 output:

```
$ openssl s_client -CAfile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt -connect svn.example.org:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=4 /L=ValiCert Validation Network/O=ValiCert, Inc./OU=ValiCert Class 2 Policy Validation Authority/CN=http://www.valicert.com//emailAddress=info@valicert.com
verify return:1
depth=3 /C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=2 /C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
verify return:1
depth=1 /C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
verify return:1
depth=0 /OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.example.org
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.example.org
   i:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
 1 s:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
   i:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
 2 s:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
   i:/C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
 3 s:/C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
   i:/L=ValiCert Validation Network/O=ValiCert, Inc./OU=ValiCert Class 2 Policy Validation Authority/CN=http://www.valicert.com//emailAddress=info@valicert.com
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[ SNIP ]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.example.org
issuer=/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5697 bytes and written 319 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: [ SNIP ]
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: [ SNIP ]
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    Start Time: 1394712184
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
DONE
```

While on CentOS 4:

```
$ openssl s_client -CAfile /usr/share/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt -connect svn.example.org:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=4 /L=ValiCert Validation Network/O=ValiCert, Inc./OU=ValiCert Class 2 Policy Validation Authority/CN=http://www.valicert.com//emailAddress=info@valicert.com
verify return:1
depth=3 /C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=2 /C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
verify error:num=7:certificate signature failure
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.example.org
   i:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
 1 s:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
   i:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
 2 s:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
   i:/C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
 3 s:/C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
   i:/L=ValiCert Validation Network/O=ValiCert, Inc./OU=ValiCert Class 2 Policy Validation Authority/CN=http://www.valicert.com//emailAddress=info@valicert.com
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[ SNIP ]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.example.org
issuer=/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5697 bytes and written 343 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: [ SNIP ]
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: [ SNIP ]
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    Start Time: 1394712595
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 7 (certificate signature failure)
---
DONE
```

Bit flummoxed at this point, any ideas appreciated.

Comment: I wish you luck. Most likely the client is going to have to upgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming cert #3 in your chain is the one at https://certs.godaddy.com/anonymous/repository.pki 
`gdroot-g2_cross.crt` with SHA1 fingerprint `84 1D 4A 9F C9 D3 B2 F0 CA 5F AB 95 52 5A B2 06 6A CF 83 22`,
that is **signed using SHA256WithRSA**. So is the actual root for `Go Daddy Root Certification Authority - G2` 
which is `gdroot-g2.crt` `47 BE AB C9 22 EA E8 0E 78 78 34 62 A7 9F 45 C2 54 FD E6 8B`,
not the one you identify `Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2` which is clearly intermediate,
apparently `gdig2.crt` `27 AC 93 69 FA F2 52 07 BB 26 27 CE FA CC BE 4E F9 C3 19 B8`.

The (one) OpenSSL 0.9.7 I have still on one of my systems, 0.9.7d, **does not support SHA-2**.
It is dated 2004, base 0.9.7 apparently was Dec. 2002, and FIPS 180-2 was published Aug. 2002.

I suggest you check your entity cert; it may also be signed with SHA256. Your #1 apparently 
is `gdig2.crt` which definitely is. If so these won't ever work in 0.9.7; you didn't see 
an error there because it had already failed further up the chain.

I'm not sure you can find a commercial CA that will issue you a SHA1-signed cert (and chain) 
after the NIST deadline took effect at the beginning of 2014; if so it probably won't remain 
valid very long and then you'll face the same problem again. If the client is willing to change 
their truststore (either the system one, without changing the code) or 
a user store used by whatever client app(s) you care about, you could just create a 
selfsigned-with-SHA1 cert for your server key using openssl and have the client(s?) trust that.
Depending on your server if you can partition the requests from lame clients to 
a different port or address, you might be able to use your homemade SHA1 cert only for them 
and your commercial SHA256 cert for everybody else.